# Define 'this' keyword in a variable

Tags: javascript

I have a function in the following format:

```
var obj = {
    doSomething: function(){
        this.callSomething();
    },
    callSomething: function(){
        this.doThis();
        this.andDoThis();
    },
    doThis: function(){
        if(!this.bln){
            this.bln = true;
        }
        // some code here
    },
    andDoThis: function(){
        if(this.bln){
            // some code here
        }
    }
}
obj.doSomething();
```

As you can see in the above code, I am using `this` keyword many times to call a function or a `obj` scoped variables.

Instead of using `this` keyword, I want to use something of single letter like:

```
var s = this;    // so that I can use "s" instead of "this" everywhere
```

How can I do this?

PS: Here `obj` object name is just for example purpose. In real scenario, the object name is longer than `this` keyword.

Comment: `this` is a language keyword which has a special meaning. Assigning it to a variable may entirely change the workings of your code, depending on when and in which scope you assign it. If you're doing this simply because you feel "`this`" is too long: don't.

Comment: @deceze I am actually trying to create a compressed plugin. and that is how I got this thought.

Comment: @deceze I am sure, `this` here refers to the object `obj`. please check the code. Every variable will be in scope of that object but not to the inside function scope.

Comment: @Mr_Green: if your code is gzipped that will have little effect on the size of the file -- you should probably look elsewhere for size reductions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get rid of `this` entirely if you use the **[module](https://carldanley.com/js-module-pattern/)** or the **[revealing module patterns](https://carldanley.com/js-revealing-module-pattern/)**.

The following example uses the revealing module pattern:

```
var module = (function() {
    var bln = false,
        doSomething = function() { callSomething(); },
        callSomething = function() { doThis(); andDoThis(); },
        doThis = function() { if (!bln) { bln = true; } },
        andDoThis = function() { if (bln) { /* do stuff */ } };

    return {
        doSomething: doSomething //Only public method, rest are private
    };

})();

module.doSomething();
```

Comment: Is there anyway to refer `module` variable inside the closure function? like `var module = (function(x) { //use x here })();`. I tried as shown above which didn't work. btw, thanks for your answer.

Comment: See how `bln` is referred. No need to pass anything, use the closure scope (that's kind of the point of the module pattern)

Comment: I actually in need to binding functions with current scope like: `element.onmousedown = doSomething.bind(this)`. Here I am ending up using `this` again..

Comment: Not really..... since doSomething doesn't have `this` in it... `element.onmousedown = doSomething`. If you want to pass the element in, you don't have much choice there.

Comment: and even for `if(!this.bln){`.. Since, I can't use `bln` variable for the first time when it is not even defined.

Comment: Please see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9rmLb7x5/. You did not give enough context to answer the question properly. You should have mentioned that this is an event and you can't give up `this`. You could try asking another question and give a *real* example instead of example pseudo code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Variable name itself can be used as `this` inside that object.

```
var longName = s = {
   doSomething: function(){
       s.callSomething();
   },
   callSomething: function(){
       s.doThis();
       s.andDoThis();
   },
   doThis: function(){
       if(!s.bln){
          s.bln = true;
       }
    // some code here
   }
   ...........................
}
```

Comment: I should have mentioned as I can't use original name i.e `obj`. In my real case, the original name is long. :)

Comment: @Mr_Green, this is useful, I have just tried it. One simple change that you could do is : var k = obj; outside the scope of obj. Due to **Hoisting** it will first create `k` by taking reference of `obj` and then it will create `obj`. Hence `k` will **ref** to `obj`

Answer (score 0):

Hi probably the above answers are correct, BUT its not a good way to do things.

It will be way harder to read your code if you go away from "this". Reading "this" you always know you are talking about the reference of your object instance.

The only reason i can think of where this could be usefull is to reduce memory by 3 byte for each "this" you replace by "s".

You would have to define s on a global scope to achieve what you actually want - which is VERY dangerous.

There is alot of blackboxing you do in javascript by implementing eg. frameworks that might ruin everything for you.